# Magento 2 custom Extension extra pages

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, custom

I am currently developing a new forum extension for my company on our Magento 2.1.8 web store.

I have made a few different extensions in the past, but they have all required only a single page;

```
www.mywebsite.com/extensionname
```

For this extension I will need to have more than one page for the different features of the forum, for example;

```
www.mywebsite.com/forum/username

www.mywebsite.com/forum/threadname
```

How would i go about implementing a system such as this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom module for it and in this module create a Controller whose front name will be **forum**.In controller folder create two folder with name **Username** and **Threadname** and this folder create php file index.php in both folders and define here your logic e.g for database logic call your Model with model name from controller file...etc.

For creating a custom module in magento 2 with Controller refer links:

https://www.pierrefay.com/magento2-training/create-controller-action-magento2.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

For any other help,let me know.

Comment: Hi akgola,

I should have clarified in my post, I know how to make a custom module and i currently have a page "www.mywebsite.com/forum" working. What i wish to do is have "www.mywebsite.com/forum/anotherpage"

I also know how to use Blocks and Controllers too

Thanks

Im new to stack exchange and keep pressing enter to get a new line instead of Shift+Enter so it keeps updating my comment before im finished!

Comment: ok @DarrylWhalley ,clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new controller you first you need to create routes.xml in below location,

app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\routes.xml

In this file, you need to write this code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="route_id" frontName="frontname">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Where frontname(ex: forum) is my route name you can replace with your

Now you need to create a layout file in below file,

app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\frontname_controler_action.xml

here you can see frontname_index_index where frontname is route name index is controller name and index is action name.

in this layout file you need to write your as per your requirement. for example :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Front TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Blockname" name="myBlock" template="Vendor_Module::templatename.phtml" />            
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the similar above way you can create other page by creating action file  parallel:
app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        // Set title of page
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('your title'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Run command :
 1.php bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Hi Shashank,

I think my initial post was not clear. I have a firm understanding of creating extensions and setting up Controllers and Blocks.

My question was regarding having further pages added to my module.

Thanks

Comment: As  I  mentioned above  , you need to create addition page with this URL , (for example: www.mywebsite.com/forum/username ) , so your route name is 'forum' and inside the controller need to create folder name 'Username'  and inside the folder create Index.php action file , as mentioned above create layout file . 
In this way you can create as many pages as you want as per your requirement .

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you it will be could to accept . Which help other in community  who is searching for similar question.